# file -i vs file property accuracy, how to check if file is text file

Tags: files, file-type

i'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS, i'm using `file -i` along with `find` and other shell commands to generate list of text files inside a folder, it works like 99.9% of time, but there're a few exceptions

from `file -i`, it's saying `text/plain`

```
$ ls -al
total 520
drwxr-xr-x 2 pi pi   4096 Dec 16 17:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 pi pi   4096 Dec 16 17:58 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 262144 Dec 16 17:58 NvStorageFtwSpare.bin

$ file -i NvStorageFtwSpare.bin
NvStorageFtwSpare.bin: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

while from file property, it's saying binary

[image]

i looked at file content using textedit, it's indeed binary, so how do i get accurate information about file being text file or not? thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`man file` says:

> file tests each argument in an attempt to classify it.  There are
> three sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests,
> magic tests, and language tests.  The first test that succeeds causes the file type to be printed.

You could try these options:

```
 -k, --keep-going
         Don't stop at the first match, keep going.  Subsequent matches will be have the string ‘\012- ’ prepended.  (If you want a
         newline, see the -r option.)  The magic pattern with the highest strength (see the -l option) comes first.

 -l, --list
         Shows a list of patterns and their strength sorted descending by magic(5) strength which is used for the matching (see also
         the -k option).
```

Comment: with `-ik` flag, it does give more information, but how does `File Property` get the actual file type?